# Adding tuple to list of lists

Tags: python, list, click, tuples

I have an empty list of lists in python players = [[],[]]. I then have a click event that results in an x and y coordinate. How do I add this (x,y) tuple into the first list in players?

Comment: Could you post what the list is supposed to look like after the x and y values are added? It's always a good idea to post both inputs and outputs!

Comment: Basically the list starts at players = [[],[]]. Then a click event happens defining x and y in the namespace, say (55,55). I want to save the tuple to the first list, making players =[[(55,55)],[]]. Then another click happens, and I want those new coordinates, say (55,105) saved into the other list, making players = [[(55,55)],[(55,105)]]. Then another click happens, say at (105,105), and i want that appended to the tuple in the first list, making players = [[(55,55),(105,105)],[(55,105)]]. this continues back and forth for a 8x8 grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
players[0].append(tuple([x, y]))
```